# How to Copy data between two different data tables with different column names in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

How to Copy data between two different datatables with different column names in C#?

```
mAD.Fill(MySqldSet, "tbltrackshipment");//Got the empty table of Mysql

// Loop through all rows of Sql server data table and add into MySql dataset
DataRow NewRow;

foreach (DataRow row in SqldSet.Tables["tblStatusTracking"].Rows)
{

    NewRow=MySqldSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
    NewRow["BL"] = row["BL"];
    NewRow["ContainerNumber"] = row["ContainerNumber"];
    NewRow["Status"] = row["Status"];
    NewRow["FinalDest"] = row["Location"];
    NewRow["StatusDate"] = row["StatusDate"];
    MySqldSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(NewRow);
}
```

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: It generates the following error -> Missing the DataColumn 'Location' in the DataTable 'tbltrackShipment' for the SourceColumn 'Locaiton'.

Comment: Add the error info to your question.

Comment: Can you post the structure of `tbltrackshipment`? Does it actually have a `FinalDest` column?

Comment: Use following : DataRow row in SqldSet.Tables["tblStatusTracking"].AsEnumerable()

Comment: What's the structure of SqldSet.Tables["tblStatusTracking"] & MySqldSet.Tables[0] ?

Comment: @vc74 Yes I have FinalDest column in tbltrackshipment the rest of the columns have similar name with the tblStatustracking

Comment: @Sira Pathre The column names are all similar on both tables except for FinalDest in tbltrackShipment and Location in tblStatustracking

Comment: Can you please check that `Tables[0]` corresponds to `tbltrackshipment` and it has a `FinalDest` column?